# Populate Typescript Class with JObject

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, migration

I'm moving from AngularJS to Angular 6, in JS I used `$resource` and when I got data back that looked like this...

```
{
  "SomeList": [{
      "SomeID": "123456",
      "SomeName": "Joe Shmoe",
      "SomeCode": "987654",
      "Address1": null,
      "Address2": null,
      "City": null,
      "State": null,
      "Zip": null,
      "Phone1": null,
      "Phone2": null,
      "Email": null

    },
    {
      "SomeID": "234567",
      "SomeName": "Joe Bagodonuts",
      "SomeCode": "456123",
      "Address1": null,
      "Address2": null,
      "City": null,
      "State": null,
      "Zip": null,
      "Phone1": null,
      "Phone2": null,
      "Email": null
    },
    etc...
  ]
}
```

It just flowed into a variable very nicely and I could use the data.

In Typescript I have set up...

***A Model***

```
export class SomeList {
  SomeID: string;
  SomeName: string;
  SomeCode: string;
  Address1: string;
  Address2: string;
  City: string;
  State: string;
  Zip: string;
  Phone1: string;
  Phone2: string;
  Email: string;
}

export class SimpleResponse < T > {
  Data: T;
}

export class SimpleResponseLower < T > {
  data: T;
}
```

***A variable set to the model in a singleton***

```
public static somies: SomeList[];
```

***A Data Service***

```
getSomeList<SomeList>(year: number): Observable<SomeList[]>{
  const url = `${Urls.Somies()}?cropYear=` + year;
  var host = window.location;
  var combineurl = host.href + 'api/RequestHandler?uri=' + url;
  return this.http.get<SimpleResponse<SomeList[]>>(combineurl).pipe(map(r => 
r.Data));

 ***The call below is what returned the sample data above
 //return this.http.get(combineurl).pipe(map(value =>{return value}));

  }
}
```

***and A call to the data service filling the class***

```
this.dataService.getSomeList < SomeList > (2018)
  .subscribe((data) => {
      this._formValues.somies = data;
    },
    () => {
      // put some code here and remove console.log
    }); // end of error block);
}
```

I've tried just about every configuration I can think of and data is coming back "undefined" with no errors and the link listed in the Network tab of the browser populating.

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: are u getting the data by browsing the url directly in the browser?

Comment: I might be wrong, but the data you're getting back doesn't have a key `Data`, and that's what you seem to be mapping to. Maybe `Data` is undefined? Have you tried returning an array of `SomeList`, since that's what the server is returning?

Comment: I am getting data back by browsing.  Data is part of SimpleReponse

Comment: But the data you said you got back doesn't say `Data` anywhere, and your model should correspond to what you get back. I believe what you get back would have to look something like this: ```{ "Data" : {
 "SomeList": [
{
  "SomeID": "123456",
  "SomeName": "Joe Shmoe",
  "SomeCode": "987654",
  "Address1": null,
  "Address2": null,
 "City": null,
  "State": null,
  "Zip": null,
  "Phone1": null,
  "Phone2": null,
  "Email": null
} etc...]} }```, if you wanted to map your response to the `Data` property. There doesn't seem to be an indication of a `SomeList` property either.

Comment: can you console.log(r) `return this.http.get<SimpleResponse<SomeList[]>>(combineurl).pipe(map(r => 
console.log(r)));` and share what does this print. @Funn_Bobby

Comment: There are a few things missing from your question. 1. Are you trying to bind this data to a form? 2. Why are you creating a model for it? I know it's recommended. But it's not really required for you to create one upfront.

Comment: If I don't use a model how can I just put this data into a generic object and use it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is breaking because its a collection of collections...Typescript doesn't seem to like having the data in the {
  "SomeList": [{Data}] }  It wants it just in [{Data}]  is there a way to clean this up in TypeScript or a way to create a collection of list?

Comment: @Funn_Bobby https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1tvtc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html Is there anything different between your code and the stackblitz?

Comment: @Wingnod Thank you so much for setting that example up!!  I made my code match exactly and the data coming back in the console looks like your data.json but my .subscribe(data) is undefined?  I did notice something strange in my data-service I'm using SomeList model but in the import statement I get a message that says " 'SomeList' is declared but it's value is never read"

Comment: It shouldn't matter in this case, since Typescript is strictly related to compile time. It will only give you intellisense suggestions based on what you told it the structure of your data will look like. However, at runtime, you will get a plain javascript object. So Typescript is there to help you when you're coding, if that makes sense. I can only imagine that the property you are mapping to doesn't exist, hence the `undefined`. Could I see a picture of the logged response data?

Comment: Yes, I'm out of town but will try to do it this evening.

Comment: {
  "SomeList": [
    {
      "SomeID": "3017185",
      "SomeName": "Joe BogOdunuts",
      "SomeCode": "243099",
      "Address1": null,
      "Address2": null,
      "City": null,
      "State": null,
      "Zip": null,
      "Phone1": null,
      "Phone2": null,
      "Email": null,
      "Master": null
    },
   Here is how the data is coming back @Wingnod...sorry for the delay I had connectivity issues

Comment: @Wingnod ...also <SomeList> is undefined in my app.component.ts

Comment: I can't find any further issue with the code, or how you're doing things. The only thing I can think of is if you're referencing your data with the wrong key, but that doesn't seem to be the case either. Sorry that I can't help you figure this out.

Comment: @Wingnod I appreciate all your help!!  I did copy the data out of the console and put it in a data.json file and it works like it's supposed to...I can't understand why it wouldn't work calling my api to get the data?  unless there is a timing issue and the service is not waiting for the data to get back?...is that a thing?

Comment: Well since it is an observable, it should only emit when it receives the response and then it completes, so I don't think the issue is timing related. In your question, you said that this line gave back some data: ```return this.http.get(combineurl).pipe(map(value =>{return value}));``` Did you get that data when you subscribed to it in your component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to figure this out.
What I had to do was...

Change the type being returned from api from

```
string jsonString = client.DownloadString(fullUri);                                
JObject infoObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
string data = infoObj.ToString();                                   
return data;
```

To

```
string jsonString = client.DownloadString(fullUri);                                
JObject infoObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);
SimpleResponse<JObject> data = new 
SimpleResponse<JObject>();
data.Data = infoObj;                                
return data;
```

and on the typeScript side I had to change the model to

```
export class SimpleResponse<data> {
data: data;
}
export class SomeResponse{
SomeList: SomeList[];
Message: string;
}
```

and in my data service instead of returning...

```
<SimpleResponse<SomeList[]>>
```

I return

```
<SimpleResponse<SomeResponse>>
```

I'm not sure if this is the "TypeScript" way of doing it or if there is a better more generic way so I don't have to add a ResposeClass for each call I make to the API...but it is working!!

Comment: I'm glad things are working out for you now! That was a long and difficult ordeal :)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON should map directly to your models.

Either your data should be:

```
'{
   "Data": [
      {
        "SomeID": "123456",
        "SomeName": "Joe Shmoe",
        "SomeCode": "987654",
        "Address1": null,
        "Address2": null,
        "City": null,
        "State": null,
        "Zip": null,
        "Phone1": null,
        "Phone2": null,
        "Email": null
      }, etc...
   ]
}
```

Or your simple response should expect `SomeList`:

```
export class SimpleResponse<T> {
   SomeList: T;
}
```

And you should map to the `SomeList` property on the response instead of `Data`.

```
return this.http.get<SimpleResponse<SomeList[]>>(combineurl).pipe(map(r 
 => r.SomeList));
```

Comment: Tried changing SimpleResponse and mapping to SomeList...still doesn't work...could it be that the object coming back is a JObject? ...and needs to be something else?

Comment: It should be a plain javascript object. Have you tried not typing it at all, and logging what you get back? It might help you figure out what the structure of the object you get back is.

Comment: ```this.http.get<any>(combineurl).pipe(tap(data
 => console.log(data));``` Something like that to see what you get.

Comment: Yes...It looks exactly like what I posted in the original question.

Comment: The error I'm getting while trying to write it out now is ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '{
  "AgencyList": [
My select control looks like this

Comment: <select name="name" id="id" class="form-control">
                    <option *ngFor="let some of _formValues.somies">{{some.SomeName}}</option>
           </select>

Comment: That's most likely because what you're mapping to isn't an array. If you have your response, you want to map your response to the `SomeList`, which is the array of items you want to display. Of course, this is what we've been trying to do all along. It should be pretty straight forward. Are you sure that the array is called `SomeList`? Otherwise it really should just be ```this.http.get<any>(combineurl).pipe(map(data => data.SomeList);```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179581/discussion-between-wingnod-and-funn-bobby).

Comment: Chat is not working for some reason...I'm wondering if ther is a Plunkr example with the same data format I have that works so I can see it?...

Comment: Examples that implement pagination tend to get a similar response to what you're getting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is breaking because its a collection of collections...Typescript doesn't seem to like having the data in the {
  "SomeList": [{Data}] }  It wants it just in [{Data}]  is there a way to clean this up in TypeScript or a way to create a collection of list?